# java.io.File cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem in Android-Studio after updating one project to the new gradle-plugin ( 14.0.2):

```
Error:Cause: java.io.File cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process may be corrupt.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle daemons and sync project</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I tried all suggested things but no success. Also this project builds fine on the console - kinda stuck here. Any hint could help.

Comment: I am not sure if those suggestions do the same as this but, have you tried **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart** ?

Comment: thanks that sounded good - but unfortunately the same problem :-(
even restarted the PC and deleted all iml and simmilar files from the project

Comment: Are you using `+` or `+=` anywhere in the build script?

Comment: Happened to me after updating AS to 1.0 RC

Answer (score 5):

The error of this type can be fixed by changing

```
plusConfigurations += project.configurations.compile
```

To:

```
plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]
```

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks h22

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. I have appengine module in project. Updating gradle config for it to 1.9.17 solved it﻿ for me

Comment: I have had also to push up all appengine dependencies to the newest version. I was using Android Studio RC 1.

Answer (score 2):

As per Ales above, updating to 1.9.17 resolved this for me. I was on 1.9.7 previously.

Specifically, in any appengine projects that you have included, update the versions in your build.gradle file for both the buildscript dependencies and general dependencies. I updated for:

buildscript dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17'
```

dependencies:

```
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.17'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.17'

compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.17'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.17'
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by the following steps

1. exit android studio
2. delete the follwing folders

   - appName/`build`
   - appName/`app/build`
   - appName/`.gradle`
3. run android studio then go to `build` > `rebuild project`

hope this work with you